# The Publish URL https://waws-prod-am2-xxx.publish.azurewebsites.windows.net/ is unreachable

Tags: azure, azure-functions

- I created a function app on Azure Portal with below configuration.

[image]

- And I created a simple HTTP trigger Function App on VS 2019 version of 16.7.6. The function is working successfuly on local machine. When I want to publish it to Azure, it returns below error;

> Publish has encountered an error. The Publish URL
> https://waws-prod-am2-xxx.publish.azurewebsites.windows.net/ is
> unreachable. The application may be stopped, restarting or
> unavailable. Try again once the publish target is available.

- The publishing summary is;

[image]

When I check the publish profile on VS (.pubxml file), I see the line

```
<PublishUrl>https://waws-prod-am2-311.publish.azurewebsites.windows.net/</PublishUrl>
```

But it should be

```
<PublishUrl>http://myfuncappdss.scm.azurewebsites.net</PublishUrl>
```

I change it manually and there is any other error that is not detected

> Publish has encountered an error. Publish has encountered an error. We
> were unable to determine the cause of the error.

It hasn't published for 2 days. Before, I published successfully. I search it on google but I couldn't find any clue.

Btw, I can reach the FTP file of the function successfully. And the function running successfully on https://myfuncappdss.azurewebsites.net/ site.
I tried it with az command also but it wasn't work, too. All my teammates can't publish also. So, the problem is not just about my computer.
Why is the PublishUrl set with wrong URL?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update:**

Thanks for Aybuke's aharing, this is the reason of the problem:

The problem base is about function publish profile. When I follow the steps, (Go to Azure Portal-->Go to function app-->Overview menu-->Get Publish Profile) I can download the publish profile of function. So, I can see the publish settings of function. "publishUrl="https://waws-prod-am2-xxx.publish.azurewebsites.windows.net:443"" This line is in the publish profile file that I downloaded. But it should be "publishUrl="https://myfuncappdss.scm.azurewebsites.net"". That is why the published zip file is sent to wrong url. So, there are some problems while creating function on Azure Portal.

**Original Answer:**

Did you encounter this error?

[image]

I notice you change publish url to `http://myfuncappdss.scm.azurewebsites.net`, please change it to `https://myfuncappdss.scm.azurewebsites.net` and try again.

If I use http, I also can not publish my function app. I don't know why the publish url is not what you want, but the az command should work. Any details when you use az command?

Change http to https, it should work.

Comment: Thank you it works now. But, why do I have to set it manually? Why the PublishURL is set with wrong URL rather than SCM url when I create function? Is it about WestEurope?

Comment: @Aybuke If you delete the publish profile and recreate, can you reproduce the problem now? I am sorry I can not reproduce...

Comment: The problem base is about function publish profile. When I follow the steps, (Go to Azure Portal-->Go to function app-->Overview menu-->Get Publish Profile) I can download the publish profile of function. So, I can see the publish settings of function. "publishUrl="waws-prod-am2-xxx.publish.azurewebsites.windows.net:443"" This line is in the publish profile file that I downloaded. But it should be "publishUrl="https://myfuncappdss.scm.azurewebsites.net"". That is why the published zip file is sent to wrong url. So, there are some problems while creating function on Azure Portal.

Comment: @Aybuke I have update what you find. Can we end this question now?:)

Comment: Thank you for updating :) But I don't have any idea why the function sets the publish url to "https://waws-prod-am2-xxx.publish.azurewebsites.windows.net:443"". This is not a publish url. Publish url should be "publishUrl="https://myfuncappdss.scm.azurewebsites.net"". Do you have any idea?

Comment: @Aybuke Maybe some errors happened on your side when the function was been created. I cann't reproduce this. You can create a new function app on your side and check whether the publish url is still wrong.

Comment: I check all cases. I try for different subscription, different storage account, different namings...The case that I didn't try for different location. I'm just allowed for West Europe. It should be about location or linux server. Anyway, it is working when I set the publishURL manually to scm url :) Thank you

Comment: Your solution was great and worked for after hours of depression. Why is the VS Team making our lives complicated?

Answer (score 8):

When I check the publish profile in Visual Studio (`.pubxml` file), I see the line:

```
<PublishUrl>https://waws-prod-am2-311.publish.azurewebsites.windows.net/</PublishUrl>
```

But it should be

```
<PublishUrl>https://myfuncappdss.scm.azurewebsites.net</PublishUrl>
```

I changed it manually and then it started working fine.

- **Step 1**: Do the above URL changes and save the `.pubxml` file
- **Step 2**: Close Visual Studio.
- **Step 3**: Open your project in Visual Studio.
- **Step 4**: Now publish, it should work as expected…

Here we have successfully deployed the Function App.

Comment: FYI: I've edited your answer so that the `<publishUrl />` elements are visible. Previously, you didn't include a code block, and so those were being misinterpreted as HTML elements, and not being rendered. As part of this, I removed the `**` around the `https` in the second configuration block. I assume this was meant to emphasize the HTTPS, but that's not possible to do that within a code block. If you meant it to be literal text, please be sure to add that back in. (I don't see why it would be intended as literal text, though it also isn't clear to be why it was being emphasized.)

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue and the problem was on the App Function Settings.
In Networking, Inbound Traffic had Access Restrictions ON.
I had to add my public IP Address and then I was able to publish.

Comment: This was actually my problem also - For some crazy reason my org has 2 domains -- Azure is on one and our local dev machines are on a different one.  Thus when trying to publish from my local machine to Azure - I was hitting the Access Restrictions.  I turned that off and I am able to publish.