# Azure function publish url is unreachable

Tags: azure, azure-functions, visual-studio-2019

My last publish was probably about three weeks ago, today, I changed the code a bit and publish. Then I ran into the error below

> Publish has encountered an error. The Publish URL
> https://functionName.scm.azurewebsites.net/ is unreachable. The
> application may be stopped, restarting or unavailable. Try again once
> the publish target is available.

The only [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64430155/the-publish-url-https-waws-prod-am2-xxx-publish-azurewebsites-windows-net-is) post I found is suggesting to correct the pubxml field

```
<PublishUrl>https://waws-prod-<something>.publish.azurewebsites.windows.net/</PublishUrl>
```

To

```
<PublishUrl>https://<function-name>.scm.azurewebsites.net/</PublishUrl>
```

In my case, it is correct already.

If I call the function by HTTP get, it behaves as usual.

I'm relevant new to azure, not sure if I missed something obvious.

Additional remarks

- It's compiled successfully.
- I never change the PublishUrl and the field value is pretty much what I posted.
- The app is running.
- The account login to VS is the same one to Azure.

Comment: Is it possible you have configured IP whitelisting or similar network restrictions for your app?

Comment: I did not and I checked the config no one else does that too

Comment: @CircleHsiao any luck? Was it caused by IP or firewall on the SCM?

Comment: @DonCheadle I deleted the instance and published it all over again in the end

Answer (score 40):

In my case was related to the **SCM Basic Auth Publishing Credentials** parameter: it should be **On** to permit Visual Studio to log-in and publish the function app.

You can find this parameter in your Function App under *Configuration -> General settings -> SCM Basic Auth Publishing Credentials*

Comment: Life saver x 2 ! thanks

Comment: That worked for me too. Only I had to restart the function and Visual Studio (not sure which one actually helped)

Comment: Another huge thank you from me! Had set up function apps before without (as far as my memory and notes are concerned) needing to change anything for publishing to work, but a new one was failing to publish with this error and I was tearing my hair out. Does anyone know if I'm wrong about this, ie was there something I missed out in the Function App creation process this time???

Comment: Thanks! They should add this to the official documentation

Answer (score 1):

First of all, make sure your function app can be compiled.

Second, the format of your publish url is no problem.

So maybe this problem is not from the Visual Studio side. please make sure the function app is not stop or restarting, the scm site is not under the protection of NETWorking and you have login the right Microsoft account in VS.

If all of above still don't work, you can try to use other deploy method. Such as [command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local?tabs=windows%2Ccsharp%2Cbash#publish) or [ftp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-ftp?tabs=portal) and [so on](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-deployment-technologies#deployment-technology-details).

And for your situation, if you just do a little change, the [incremental deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-continuous-deployment) may be a better choice.

Answer (score 1):

In my case opening azure functions app in my browser helped. Until that it was giving error when I try to publish it in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

I saw this error happen when somebody else on my team deleted the storage account the function app was using. Because I was unaware of this deletion, it was hard to connect the details from the error to a missing storage account.

Once I recreated it, with the same specifications of a storage account that can be auto-created during a function’s first deployment, I was able to re-configure my function to use it, and I was able to deploy again from Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I didn't realize I had set up IP restrictions as this was a function app I had published a long time ago so obviously my IP had by this point changed. For me, the solution involved:

1. Select your Azure Function app in the portal
2. Under the "Settings" section click "Networking"
3. Under "Inbound Traffic" I had "Access Restriction" set to "On". If this is your case, click on "Access Restriction". If this is not your case, then this solution won't solve your problem.
4. My "Unmatched rule action" was set to deny. At the bottom, I had only my old IP and my API Management IPs listed as "Allow.
5. Click "+Add", enter whatever name that's descriptive (like "My home ip"), make sure action is set to "Allow", set a priority (in my case the priority didn't matter), I skipped description, and for type I chose IPv4 and for IP Address Block I entered my current IP address. Skip the rest of the settings.
6. At the bottom click "Add rule"
7. Don't forget to click "Save" at the top left after that
8. Not sure if you have to restart your function app, I did because it didn't impact me.
9. I alt-tabbed back to Visual Studio and published again: this time worked perfectly.